# AWS S3 Checkout Policy to avoid overwriting

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am trying to utilize a set stored in S3 to maintain a list of IDs. However, I have a slight problem. The set is supposed to be updated with a new ID via a lambda function whenever a new post is created, but I'm concerned about overwriting if two posts were made at the same time. This would result in 2 separate instances of the set being pulled from S3, and one of the users would overwrite the other's data and one of the IDs would be "lost". Is there a way to implement some sort of queue so that the object will only be pulled after the lambda function has already updated the object from the previous pull?

Comment: you can limit the lambda to a concurrency of 1 ensuring that no two processes run at the same time. That of course limits the throughput and won't work appropriately if you have lets say 10M events per day / hour but at that point your S3 approach with one single point of synchronizaiton would not work anyway.

Answer (score 1):

I have not implemented it myself, but why not try to turn versioning on for your S3 bucket.Then you cannot overwrite by accident because it will always have a version for each time something is written to the file. You just need to enhance you Lambda code to work then with file versions for the file object written. If you have access to DynanoDb then maybe rather use it to do "Conditional Updates" for your IDs.That way you have a light weight mechanism to garantee that you do not overwrite without being aware of it.